# Map subdomain to specific folder

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, server, dns

I've got 3 Laravel site's on the same (ubuntu) server:

```
domain1.de
domain2.nl
domain3.com
```

On `domain3.com` I've got 2 subdomains defined:

```
sub1.domain3.com
sub2.domain3.com
```

Now I want to map (no redirect because I want to keep the url):

`sub1.domain1.de` > `sub1.domain3.com`

`sub2.domain2.nl` > `sub2.domain3.com`

Is this possible or should I use a separated server for this? I'm using [Laravel forge](https://forge.laravel.com/servers) for server management, my dns records are at cloudflare.

Comment: What do you want to map (redirect)? The Laravel root directory, the public folder, ....?

Comment: There is a thread here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/subdomain-map-to-subdirectory-route-in-existing-laravel-project